# MySQL Query For Latest Record Before a Date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a MySQL database which stores LogID, unix timestamp, temperature, humidity and light level.  I am trying to get a query that extracts the last record before a set date & time.  My data is as follows:

```
|69511|2017-04-24 19:53:23|19.8|52.7|1.76
|69512|2017-04-24 20:07:57|20|53.8|1.86
|69513|2017-04-24 20:12:00|20.1|54.9|1.07
|69514|2017-04-24 20:29:58|20.2|53.8|1.95
```

So if the required date was 2017-04-24 20:10:00 the query would return the record:

```
|69512|2017-04-24 20:07:57|20|53.8|1.86
```

as the first record preceding 2017-04-24 20:10:00.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a WHERE clause to limit your search to records before the date in question, then sort in descending order by the timestamp (sorting by ID will probably work as well) and take the first record with LIMIT 1.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE ts_column < '2017-04-24 20:10:00'
ORDER BY ts_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

I improvised the name of your table & timestamp column, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Timestamps vs. quality answers = The better ones are always just that; *better* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Filter the records in where clause using the timestamp. Sort it by descending order and get the top 1 record using limit.

```
select  * from table_name
where unix_timestamp  < '2017-04-24 20:10:00' 
order by unix_timestamp desc
limit 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
 SELECT * FROM {tablename} WHERE {timestamp column} < '2017-04-24 20:10:00' LIMIT 1
```

EDIT: add 'order by unix_timestamp desc'

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard noted